# Angular 7: Singleton service not working after routing

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two urls `/login` and `/home`. When I log in I want to store the username in a field of the LoginService. This is done on the `/login` page. Now when I go to `/home` it's like the service gets created again and all the fields are empty.

This is my service

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class LoginService {

    public CURRENT_USER: User;
}
```

this is how I get the service in my components

```js
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {}
}
```

and here's is my routing module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import SignUpComponent from './components/sign-up/signup.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignUpComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Now am I missing something or am I doing my routing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `import SignUpComponent from './components/sign-up/signup.component';`

why is this import different? (no brackets {})

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli it's just that I used `export default class SignupComponent`

Comment: Were you able to figure out why was it happening? I am facing the same issue and I am sure that I am not providing the same service anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you want to do, I suggest you to :

1. Store `CURRENT_USER` on the local storage and retrieve him whenever you want 
   (`user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(CURRENT_USER));`)
2. Set `CURRENT_USER` as `Observable` and `subscribe()` to it on the component/s you want

There is nothing to do with your routing implementation.It is how Angular life-cycle works.

**UPDATE**
For the 2nd option :
Create a new Service (`UserService`)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class Userservice {
    private subject = new Subject<User>();

    sendUser(currentUser: User) {
        this.subject.next(currentUser);
    }


    getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

When you login :

```
constructor(private userService: UserService) {}
login() {
  this.userService.sendUser(CURRENT_USER);
}
```

On the component you want to get the current user :

```
user: User;
constructor(private userService: UserService) {
  this.userService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(currentUser => {
    this.user = currentUser;
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't really want to store my user details in the localStorage. I've modified the field as `public CURRENT_USER: Observable<User> = new Observable();`. Now how do I update the data? Also how can a non loaded component be subscribed to it?

Comment: I have updated my answer in order to see in details what I mean with my 2nd proposal.

Answer (score 3):

make sure that you redirect to HomeComponent with standard way of angular ( for example : routerLink ) . if you use Complete route , your page will be Refresh and after that all service are empty .

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely providing the service somewhere else. Search for all instances of the LoginService and make sure that you are not providing it in another module or component.

If it appears in the provides array of another module or component you will not have a global singleton instance of the service.

Comment: Yeah, that's not the case. Thanks!